# payment through iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, itunes, payment-gateway

I have a question about payments through an app. Are there any type of payments you can do without apple applying their 30% cut?

from my understanding, apple's stand is if your application generates any new revenue, that apple is entitled to 30% of the revenue since they are providing the service and hardware that gets you that new revenue.

we are a subscription based service (we sign customers up outside of the app either though our website or in person). we use the app to access our data in a mobile form.

we recently began offering a new service where we need to charge them per usage (its outside of the subscription fee). this is a service for existing customers and the app has not attracted a new revenue source. all services available in the app are available through our website or in person.

we sell a service and access to our database, no physical goods. the new service will be available through the application, but not used in the application.

we would process the payment on our own servers (do not use services like paypal). they can always make a payment through our website or in person. we would either store their credit card information on our servers or prompt them to enter it.

it is a matter of convenience for our customers to do a payment through the app.

will apple insist on taking their cut do you believe?

EDIT:

how do credit card companies handle payments in their apps? are they paying apple 30% per payment you make to your card? or are they an exception to the rules? does apple believe that allowing big credit card companies to accept payments w/out taking a cut help apple in the long run as an attraction?

Comment: Not going to happen. Check out "Lodsys v. Apple". Even if you bypass Apple and do your own mobile payment service, you're going to get your rump sued off by patent trolls. How do you think you'll get your app through the App store approval process when it violates Apple's own rules on payments? Apple won't even allow off-device payments for on-device usage.

Comment: Apple are pretty rigid that if you're selling digital services or content in an iOS App, you must go through the StoreKit. The only exception really is when you're selling physical goods (like you have an online storefront), you can then directly take payment without including Apple or using the StoreKit.

Comment: Can someone please explain me how Groupon app works ?

Comment: @Amit : The Groupon app does not appear to be selling or collecting payments for digital content usable within the app itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If users pay to unlock digital content within your app then you must use In-App purchases, for which Apple will take their 30% cut.
If however the unlocked services are for 'real world' goods or they are not accessible within the app then you must use another payment method with no cut taken.

[Overview of In-App Purchase](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself if you need to include the payment side of things in the app. While Apple has gotten a bad rap for taking a cut from services, a lot of that depends on what type of service you are offering. Netflix isn't giving up 30%. The big reason for this is they don't allow you to collect payments through the app. If you venture down the road of trying to skirt around Apple's in-app payment, you are likely to get burned. There are ways around it for sure, but eventually they can catch on and require you to implement IAP for signups.

There is nothing wrong with requiring users to handle the business end of things on your website. This will avoid any ruffled feathers with Apple.

Comment: Bill Brasky, does Groupon pay 30% to apple for there payment collected from iPhone device ?

Comment: Never used it, so I can't say for sure. If you have to enter your appleID and password to pay, then you can can bet Apple is taking 30%. My understanding is that the cut apple is looking for is aimed at media and consumables (magazines, books, movies, etc) and less at SaaS companies like Netflix. There have been exceptions, but definitely not the rule.

Comment: You don't use apple ID and password in Groupon app. You have to enter your Credit card information in simple UITextField and done.

Comment: There you go. I guess the same goes for the RedBox app now that I think about it. So there is precedent to bill directly without involving Apple.

Comment: Check my answer, what you think ?

Comment: we don't have any intention of trying to skirt apple policy or do any work arounds. a work around may work for awhile, but at any point it could be rejected or worse (piss apple off and be banned).

Comment: @AmitVyawahare Groupon does not sell digital services/goods. It sells physical goods. Apple allows you to collect money in the app for physical services/goods without going through StoreKit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the same mechanism what Groupon is using. They collect the information from Mobile app and feed the data to there payment server and they are good to go i think.

[image: Attcahed screen shot from Groupon app]

Comment: this is the method that we would collect payments. we would ask the user to enter the information and pass it directly to our servers to process the payment. we do require each user to login to our servers.

Comment: i guess i wonder if companies like Groupon are the exceptions to the rule since they are such large and well know/well used companies that apple is willing to allow them to do this where as a small company like us, we aren't special enough for them to allow us to do this.

Comment: @Log139 Groupon does not sell digital content or services. They sell real world, physical goods. You are allowed to sell those and collect the money yourself. You can't sell a subscription to digital content, however, unless you use StoreKit.

Comment: But on the contradiction to my post, Apple does have some patent on there name that involve to sell ticket and some other stuff from Apple payment system only. Check this link http://www.geeky-gadgets.com/latest-apple-patent-reveals-movie-app-to-buy-tickets-with-your-iphone-10-06-2011/